# Is it possible within a browser to verify the client's CA/PKI trust chain is the "correct" chain?

Tags: ssl, webbrowser-control, client-certificates, pki, trust

This question is best asked visually, but the verbiage is: is it possible (within the scope, and confines of, modern browser/server technology), to verify that a "secure" SSL/TLS connection established *to my own server* is done so using a known ("correct"/"secure") trust chain, on the client's side?

I.e.:

How can I accept this (assuming I am `github.com`):
[image]

While (politely?) declining this: [image]

Or, in other words, [Verifing the TLS Certificate Chain ~~With Openssl~~](https://avilpage.com/2019/11/verify-tls-certificate-chain-with-openssl.html),  but in-band, without access to the `openssl` executable, or anything besides the connection itself)?

Comment: FWIW, I have no idea what PKI.js is/does... it just sounded promising.

Comment: So, although your browser trusts 'Ad Guard' certificates, you want something to run on the client (JavaScript presumably) that breaks that trust?  Why not simply remove the 'Ad Guard' certificate from your trust-anchor store?  Or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Seems like you want to "un"-trust ad guard from your browser. Is that right? On most browsers you would do something like settings/security/certificates and then make sure the rood certificate for ad guard is not listed, but the digicert root and intermediate certificates ARE listed. For example in chrome you would go to settings/privacy and security/manage certificates. Not sure about Safari.